# Scalability of explicit object monitoring mechanisms

Tags: windows

I was going through [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/managing-object-lifetimes-through-reference-counting) about COM where the disadvantages of using explicit object monitoring systems for managing the lifetime of COM objects are mentioned:

> "Furthermore, a mechanism based on explicit monitoring would not tend to scale toward many thousands or millions of objects."

As I am new to this field I don't quite get what is meant by that. Can anyone explain what this means in a simpler sense? To be specific, why wouldn't such a mechanism tend to scale toward many thousands of objects? Doesn't more objects imply more resources required for the monitoring system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole paragraph containing this sentence is just a blurb telling how costly
it would be if the object needed to communicate continuously with its users to find
if it needs to delete itself. The communication cost would be too high in the case
of many users.

The next paragraph says how wonderful it would be if the users are the ones that will
tell the object if they disconnected.

Comment: I am still a little bit confused. I get that the cost of an external mechanism for communication increase with an increase in user or objects. Wouldn't the system be then said to scale towards the number of objects/users, instead of "not scale" towards it?

Comment: It scales, only with less communications.

Comment: Pardon my intrusive nature towards the tiniest bit of information, but am I correct in assuming that by "would not tend to scale" the sentence is referring to the system's inability to reduce resource requirements when the number of objects is large.

Comment: No, to excessive network messaging.